# Python - Tweepy - AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'retweeted_status'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

When I run the following piece of code I get the error: `AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'retweeted_status'`

```
for tweet in Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user_name,count=200).items(3200):
        is_tweet_reply = True if tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name != "" else False
        is_tweet_retweet = True if tweet.text[0:3] == "RT " else False

        if is_tweet_retweet == True:
            original_tweeter_name = tweet.retweeted_status.user.screen_name
            original_tweeter_id = tweet.retweeted_status.user.id
            original_tweet_id = tweet.retweeted_status.id
        else: 
            original_tweeter = None
            original_tweeter_id = None
            original_tweet_id = None
```

Any possible solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a `try except` block to get the retweeted tweets.

```
for tweet in Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user_name,count=200).items(3200):
        is_tweet_reply = True if tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name != "" else False

        try:
            original_tweeter_name = tweet.retweeted_status.user.screen_name
            original_tweeter_id = tweet.retweeted_status.user.id
            original_tweet_id = tweet.retweeted_status.id
        except AttributeError:
            original_tweeter = None
            original_tweeter_id = None
            original_tweet_id = None
```